# How to select multiple items from the list

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2

Currently I have this list with some jscript added to it, and this list gets the categories from a `SOLR`. My question is, how can I get more items from my select?

```
<script src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var cat= ["C"];
        $("#cat").select2({
          data: cat
        });
    });
</script>
<select name="cat[]" id="cat" >
    <option value="all">Categories</option>
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    <option value="C">Hawaji</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Sorry I tagged php instead of html

Comment: `<select name="cat[]" id="cat" multiple>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

   var keys = [];

   $("#countries").change(function(event){
     var thi = $(this).val();
     keys.push(thi);
     alert('Array length: '+keys.length);

   });

});

 <select name="countries" id="countries" multiple>
         <option value="">Select ...</option>
         <option value="EN">England</option>
         <option value="GR">Greece</option>
         <option value="US">USA</option>
         <option value="IT">Italy</option>
       </select>
```

Comment: Your answer is great, there is 1 minor issues. The fact that the list looks very ugly, because it doesn't have the arrow down http://imgur.com/a/EwQua

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to add to an array and want to send the values using a form action you can just set the multiple attribute for the select list:

```
<select name="cat" id="cat" multiple >
    <option value="all">Categories</option>
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    <option value="C">Hawaji</option>
</select>
```

Example: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple